# jQuery event when specific option is selected with Ajax HTML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, select

I would like to create a jQuery event when a particular option is selected. I am familiar how to do this with a general dropdown structure, but mine is a but unusual and it doesn't work:

**HTML**

```
<span class="input-wrapper">
    <select name="country" id="billing_country" class="country_select" autocomplete="country" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select a country…</option>
        <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
        <option value="NL" selected="selected">Netherlands</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select2-container" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-billing_country-container" role="combobox">
                <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-billing_country-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Belgium" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Belgium</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

My **jQuery** attempt:

```
jQuery('#billing_country').change(function(){
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete( function() {
        if( jQuery('#select2-billing_country-container').attr('title') == 'Netherlands'){
            jQuery('#billing_address_2_field').addClass('hide'); // random event
        }
    });
});
```

The above situation is that the `<option>` is not changing with the `selected="selected"` attribute when you select another country. The only thing that changes is the attribute `title` from `#select2-billing_country-container`. And when you change the selection Ajax is also involved.

What am I missing or how can this be better?

---

**Update**
The above jQuery was in general correct, it had some conflicts with other jQuery functions. The only thing that it made it different, was the fact that on page load the dropdown structure is using the general `<select><option>` elements, but when selecting a different option it turns into an Ajax request, using the `<span>`. So above and with Doug's answer gave a full result.

Comment: Where is the element with an id of billing_country?  All I see is an ID for country.

Comment: @DougF Yes I have improved it. However that's not the issue here, I modified the original html a little.

Comment: The thing is, you're not making any kind of Ajax request, so the code under your ajaxComplete is not going to execute.  Also, you have no div with a class of element, so you're not going to see anything happen anyway.

Comment: I took a look on the checkout page and looked for it with jQuery("div.element") but it didn't return anything.

Comment: Please look for the actual elements on line 17 in the sources console, JS-file is called `checkout-page.js`

Comment: OK, you have a line of code that says this jQuery('billing_address_2_field').css('display', 'block') which doesn't find anything.  I think you want jQuery('#billing_address_2_field').css('display', 'block') to find an element with that ID (you're missing the # in the selector), but let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: It seems to work now, I have removed some other functions in the code.

Comment: OK, I see that the actual select menu is being hidden while it's replaced by a span that looks like a dropdown.  However, I also noticed that the hidden select menu still has Belgium as being selected even though I selected The Netherlands.  Is that your issue?  Sorry if I'm being dense here.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a weird behaviour in general, it changes from a regular dropdown menu into an ajax span when make a change. But I need to hide the second address line for Netherlands. It's doing that now when you change, but not on page load when it's pre-selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

On page load, the select menu is being looked at, not the HTML structure, so on page load you need to have this code:

```
    if( jQuery('#billing_country').val() == 'NL'){
        jQuery('#billing_address_2_field').css('display', 'none');
    }
```

and you can leave your change event as you have it on your page now.

Comment: Could you take a look at the original page? Because this is what I have done, except not using the `function HideAddressTwo`. I just fully coded it. On page load, when the country is pre-selected, it's not working.

Comment: @Demian Yes I see what you mean.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, such a small detail, it did the trick. Thanks for your time and effort. Highly appreciated.

Comment: It's always the little details isn't it?  :)  Glad to help and have a good rest of your day.